# orthogonal projector onto the set of convex functions

Tags: hilbert-spaces, convex-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ be an open, convex domain, and consider the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega)$. Each sum of convex functions is convex, hence the subset $Conv(\Omega)$ of all convex functions is convex. I also have the strong impression that $Conv(\Omega)$ is closed wrt the $L^2$-norm, in spite of the fact that its elements are continuous. So, there exists a projector of $L^2(\Omega)$ onto $Conv(\Omega)$. Can one say how it looks like?

Comment: Nice question.  Even $\Omega = (0,1)$ seems interesting.

Comment: What do you get if you just take convex quadratic functions?

Comment: What about the Fenchel bi-conjugate? That gives in a sense the "nearest" convex function....?

Comment: Thanks @Suvrit, I didn't know at all about the theory you mention, and it sounds promising. In a certain sense it sounds very "continuous", in fact it is not clear to me whether any connection with the $L^2$-norm may be expected - meaning that the $f^{**}$ should actually be the one convex function of minimal $L^2$-distance from $f$.

Comment: @Suvrit Is there actually a handier formula for $f^{**}$? In principle one should be able to check whether $f^{**}$ is the best approximation of $f$ in $Conv(\Omega)$ by checking whether $(f-f^{**},g-f^{**})\le 0$ for all $g\in Conv(\Omega)$.

Comment: Not sure about this; however, note that $f^{**} \le f$ (restricted to the domain of $f$), which is the sense of "nearest" that I meant.

Comment: @Suvrit thanks, but I admit I don't quite get this. What about $f:x\mapsto -x^2$ on $\mathbb R$? How can a convex function be dominated pointwise by a concave function going to $-\infty$? Or does one have to give up the condition that $f^{**}$ is proper?

Comment: @DelioMugnolo ok that shows that maybe it may be better to **not** use binconjugates (in your example, $f^{**}\equiv -\infty$, hence useless), but perhaps to decompose $f(x) = f_{\text{cvx}} + f_{\text{cve}}$ into convex and concave parts (not always possible, but often it is). For instance, at least for twice differentiable functions, the Hessian will provide the way, but more generally not sure what recipe to follow...

Comment: @Suvrit I am not sure I understand your decomposition, either. What about the sine function? How can it be possibly decomposed into a convex and a concave part?
Btw, the above stated inequality shows that the key of the solution to the problem should be to understand the behaviour of $f-f^{**}$, or perhaps simply of $f-Pf$ ($P$ the projector).

(Before we make a forum out of these comments, we may perhaps move to a chat)

Comment: These decompositions are not unique, and finding the "best" such decomposition could give an idea in practice. I'd also prefer to move all of this to chat (except in chat, math does not work, so...); as for $\sin(x)$ have a look at this post and the comments to D. Speyer's answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13386   --- but on second thought, $f^{**}$ is perhaps the right object to consider....(or $f-f^{**}$).

Comment: Thanks! Although Willie Wong's comment makes the whole a bit hopeless...